# Why a hanging program increases its memory usage

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-leaks

A C++ background program developed in Visual Studio, called `monitor`, watches another program, called `target`, and restarts it each time it exits. A somewhat simplified version of the program is shown below.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <Process.h>

void BindToProcess();

const WCHAR PATH[] = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";
const WCHAR EXE[] = L"notepad.exe";

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd)
{
    do
    {
        BindToProcess();
        _wspawnl(_P_WAIT, PATH, PATH, NULL);
    } while (TRUE);
    return 0;
}

void BindToProcess()
{
    HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;

    // Take a snapshot of all processes in the system.
    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;

    // Set the size of the structure before using it.
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    // Retrieve information about the first process,
    if (!Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32))
    {
        CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
        return;
    }

    // Now walk the snapshot of processes, and search for target
    do
    {
        const int len = (int) wcsnlen_s(EXE, 10);
        if (CompareStringW(0, 0, pe32.szExeFile, len, EXE, len) == CSTR_EQUAL)
        {
            HANDLE handle[1];
            handle[0] = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
            WaitForMultipleObjects(1, handle, TRUE, INFINITE);
            CloseHandle(handle[0]);
            CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
            return;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));
    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
    return;
}
```

`Monitor` first checks to see if `target` is running and, if so, binds itself to it. It stays inactive until `target` exists. Then it restarts `target` and again stays inactive until `target` exists, just to restart it once more.

In the mockup program, I use notepad.exe as the target. In the real system, it is an application that searches the internet and displays the results in a graphical user interface. In practice, `target` never exits unless deliberately killed, so `monitor` does not loop; it stays hanging. Nevertheless, I observe that its memory grows.

`Monitor` never uses `new()` or `malloc()` to allocate memory. The only allocations occur in the calls to `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` and `OpenProcess()`, but the corresponding memory is released through calls to `CloseHandle()`. Therefore, no memory leaks should ever occur, even if the program was looping, but it doesn't, it hangs.

Why does a hanging program's memory grow? I observe both memory increases and memory decreases, but in the long run, memory grows.

Comment: I don't see any issue in the code and I don't observe any memory increase in your program when running (compiled release and debug x64, running on Windows x64) I keep closing notepad and it opens again but memory is stable.

Comment: Can't we simplify your [mre] by getting rid of `BindToProcess`?  The only thing looping is, well, your loop, so that's the only thing that can contribute to memory usage increasing over time.  Also, how are you monitoring / measuring memory usage please, and is this a Debug or Release build?  Thx.

Comment: @Paul Sanders: I observe slow memory changes both through ``tasklist`` in ``cmd`` and in ``resmon``. I mostly saw this phenomenon in a release version of the program. I have to check ``BindToProcess``.

Comment: @Paul Sanders: The objective with ``BindToProcess`` is to bind even if target was started earlier. I think you can remove it but it where memory allocations occur.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about `BindToProcess` - it's only called once.  But you might be chasing shadows.  Regular allocations and deallocations - even if there's no leak - can cause memory consumption as seen by the OS to creep upwards for a variety of reasons, for a while at least.  Does it ever stabilise? Did you run it overnight, say?

Comment: @Paul Sanders: I'm not sure if the memory changes stabilize; I've observed them too briefly. ``Monitor`` is running currently on my PC, and the three most recent memory sizes are 944, 864, and 788 K. So it has gone down, but the oldest size I can still see is 568 K. Now, the truth is that in my real program, BindToProcess is also inside the loop. However, ``monitor`` does not loop; ``target`` has never gone down.

Comment: Ah well, you moved the goalposts.  Please post a [mre] that exhibits the problem, nothing more, nothing less.  And I would run it overnight to get a true figure.

Comment: @Paul Sanders: I've moved ``BindToProcess`` into the loop so now it is like my program.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Now I would run it overnight and see how it's doing in the morning.

Comment: Another thing to try is to attach to your program with a debugger once it's running and see if there are any other threads besides your main one. Something else on your system may have created a thread in your process and that thread may be responsible for the memory use.

Comment: @Paul Sanders: After the night, I notice that the memory allocation varies widely and can go up and down. So my conclusion is that what I see is not ``monitor's`` memory; it must be **the sum** of ``monitor`` and ``target``. There is no other way to explain this. I primarily use ``tasklist | findstr monitor`` in a console window to observe the memory changes. As usual, ``target`` didn't stop and ``monitor`` didn't loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the information accessed by your program is variable.

`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` does not always have the same memory usage because it is a snapshot of processes at any given time. Processes vary a lot, some can close and others can start.

And the snapshotted process information varies too. For example you are checking `szExeFile` which does not have a fixed size.

Also, memory allocation is sometimes done in blocks. So one run can reserve a block that is bigger or smaller, depending on what is available.

As long as the memory does not grow indefinitely this behavior is normal.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that there is something else besides my code that causes memory variations, but I expect it to be "bigger" than ``CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()``. You are correct that memory changes occur in 8 kB blocks. Let me observe the program some more and I will approve the answer. Comparing strings with ``CompareStringW()`` is quite safe; you compare at most the given amount, or less if the string is shorter.